# How to check if cell's elements contain matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a cell described as the following:

```
  mixed_values = {'jim', 89, [5 2 1; 1 2 3]};
  mixed_values{1}    
  mixed_values{2}
  mixed_values{3}
```

I loop it:

```
for k=1:length(mixed_values)
  curstate=mixed_values{k};

% Check for the [5 2 1; 1 2 3]
if ismatrix(curstate)
    disp('yes');

else
   disp('no') 
end  
end
```

But it founds the matrix multiple times.

```
yes
yes
yes
```

How to check it by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Matlab help:

> ismatrix(M) returns logical 1 (true) if SIZE(M) returns [m n]  with
>   nonnegative integer values m and n, and logical 0 (false) otherwise

so I checked `size(curstate)`

```
1 3 % 3 character string array
1 1 % of course you can do size of a single elements
2 3
```

so I modified your code

```
for k=1:length(mixed_values)
  curstate=mixed_values{k};

    % Check for the [5 2 1; 1 2 3]
    if (size(curstate,1)) > 1 && (size(curstate,2)) > 1 
        disp('yes');
        disp(size(curstate));

    else
       disp('no') 
    end  
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I'm struggling with this one, I even tried finding a way by inspecting m*n things but couldn't managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you define a matrix to be.  In MathWorks case they decided that a matrix would be something with a valid size, which is certainly true.  Notice that even scalars are matrices, of size 1x1.  You can even have a matrix of characters.  `A = ['a' 'b';'c' 'd'];`.  I gather that in your case you want a matrix to be a numerical collection of at least 2 dimensions.  I would solve it this way:

```
function result = TestForMatrix(m)
    t1 = isnumeric(m);
    t2 = ~isvector(m);
    result = all([t1 t2]);
end
```

Use it as if it was `ismatrix`.

```
if (TestForMatrix(curstate))
    disp('yes');
else
    ....
```

The way this works is the test for numerical numbers will eliminate character strings.  The second test will eliminate vectors and scalars.  As you find more things to include or eliminate you add those tests.  For example, say you want to allow cells.  `t3 = iscell(m); result = all([t1 t2 t3]);`  The are many logical tests that can be done on Matlab objects, see [Matlab is*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/is.html).

Comment: Thanks that's sure will benefit me later, thanks again